# New Exchange 2013 Installation - Outlook Connections

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

I have a brand new installation of Microsoft Exchange 2013 on a Windows Azure hosted virtual machine. I've never installed Exchange before, so, I'm still leaning where the little things are. The installation seems to have gone well, but I can't get clients to connect via Outlook 2013.

I know e-mail works, because if I log in to the box locally, open OWA on the local browser, I can send and receive e-mail that way, but Outlook won't connect. I've tried connecting to it as Exchange, IMAP, and POP3. The Outlook AutoDiscover just says that it's unable to locate any Encrypted or Unencrypted settings for my domain.

Since this is hosted on Azure, I'm almost certain it would have something to do with the port forwarding/NAT they have going on--I have POP3/S, IMAP/S, SMTP/S all forwarded to that host. My DNS is hosted at NameCheap, which points mail.mydomain.com as an A Record to the VIP at Azure.

If anyone might be able to point me in a direction to troubleshoot, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is needing ports 80/443 to get Outlook Anywhere running, but test your configuration using the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/).

It should tell you at what point you're having an issue and recommended remediation steps.

Comment: I just ran the test connectivity tool, which is great, thanks. It at least gave me the URLs to try.

Comment: Thanks! I gave it an SRV record as denoted here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940881, and it worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use autodiscover, you also need HTTPS forwarded, and to have actually configured Autodiscover, which involves public DNS records. Have you done that? Did you read any install documents at all?

Comment: Aye, it would be silly to install without at least looking at the installation guides provided by Microsoft. I just did a quick google of the terms 'exchange 2013 autodiscover' and it revealed what you said about HTTPS, but it's also unable to find any connections based on IMAP or POP3.

Comment: Ah ha, I gave my hosting service the SRV record, and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Autodiscover is performed over HTTPS, so if you don't have that, no autoconfigured connections will work at all. Since you didn't give any troubleshooting details at all about POP or IMAP, I didn't even address that part of your question.